# void_t in parameter list works but not as return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

There's an example on cppreference about the using alias. This example fails because `int` has no member `foo`:

```c++
template<typename...> using void_t = void;
template<typename T> void_t<typename T::foo> f();
f<int>(); // error, int does not have a nested type foo
```

This is clear, but when I tried putting the `void_t` part in the parameter list it unexpectedly compiled:

```c++
template<typename...> using void_t = void;
template<typename T> void f(void_t<typename T::foo>);
f<int>();
```

It compiles on clang but not in gcc. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

there is an ambiguity in the C++11 standard about whether non-used template parameters to template using aliases that are invalid types/expressions are a substitution failure or not.

gcc and clang interpreted the clause differently, which is what I think you are seeing.  The above `void_t` should make it work the same in both gcc and clang.

Comment: Clang is usually correct about CWG1558-related issues, and the second snippet in the OP also compiles on GCC trunk, which is supposed to have implemented the resolution of CWG1558 as well. Something odd is going on here...probably has to do with having a parameter of type `void`.

Comment: @T.C. true.  Yet despite my arrogance, the above does actually cause clang to fail, as you might expect.  It does seem strange to use templates to create a `void f(void)` function: I could have fun with this.  `template<class T> void f(std::conditional_t< std::is_same<T,int>{}, T, void >)`.  [Heh, doesn't work in clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a3b4eba9c5b162b), nor [in gcc](http://ideone.com/Nl2R7n).  Good, that would be a nightmare of special cases!

Comment: Interesting - N4140 [dcl.fct]/p4: "A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is equivalent to an empty parameter list." Of course, then the question is whether `void_t<typename T::foo>` is dependent...

Comment: @T.C. It is an alias for a dependent type in my implementation above.  If I was to guess, I'd say alias to dependent type is pretty dependent", but could be wrong.  In the case of `template<class...>using void_t=void;` it ... may be different.

Comment: Yes, alias to dependent type is dependent. The pure alias template case is the confusing one. Reading the currently active DRs for [temp.alias] reveals many...interesting...examples.

Comment: And with the `voider` version, it never compiles even for a type with a nested type `foo`, as expected.